# match two arrays into one array. Not through the for loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays

```
var arrayA = [false, false, false, false, false]
var arrayB = [1,2,3]
```

Array B holds the index of array A.
For example, the first object of array B is 1. Means that the value of the array A index is 1 to be changed

Now I want to create a `newArray: [false,true,true.true,false]`

How to make it? Thanks in advance.

One way is 2 for loops. Is there a simpler and more efficient method?

Comment: more efficent? Unlikely, a for cycle would be the most efficient way here. You need only one for-loop. I am not sure why you would need two.

Comment: @Sulthan.yeah. you are right. just one for-loop.like 
for index in arrayB. then change arrayA value. but I want to know.How can I use Map to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need two for loops, you just need one to loop over `arrayB`:

```
for index in arrayB {
    arrayA[index] = true // or maybe arrayA[index] = !arrayA[index]
}
```

Or with `forEach`:

```
arrayB.forEach { arrayA[$0] = true }
```

You might want to check for any out-of-range elements in `arrayB` before doing this:

```
arrayB = arrayB.filter { $0 >= 0 && $0 < arrayA.count }
```

Comment: .To enumerate the smaller array is always more *efficient*.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very detailed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `enumerated` (to get both index and element) and `compactMap`

```
let newArray = arrayA.enumerated().compactMap {arrayB.contains($0.offset) ? !$0.element : $0.element}
```

Not sure how efficient this is and what is considered efficient enough

As suggested by @Alladinian in a comment, this can be shortened further and also there is no need to use compactMap in this case

```
let newArray = arrayA.enumerated().map {arrayB.contains($0.offset)}
```

Comment: You beat me for a couple of seconds :P But why not `arrayA.enumerated().map { arrayB.contains($0.offset) }` ?

Comment: Ah, that is certainly a way to make it even shorter.

Comment: Thank you.I have to understand "compactMap"

Comment: For this to be efficient for arrays of non-trivial size, first you have to convert `arrayB` to a `Set`. Currently this has quadratic complexity and using `Set` you can achieve linear.

Answer (score 1):

The most minimal way of doing this from my perspective is to do:

```
arrayB.forEach( { arrayA[$0].toggle() } )
```

Be aware that this would only work if the values in arrayB is an index in arrayA.
Consider Index Out of Bound exceptions just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score -2):

```
var newArray = arrayA.map((item, index) => arrayB.indexOf(index) != -1 ? item : !item);
```

Comment: I think it's rather Js than swift